# Manipulate order of WPF TextBox LostFocus event and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a WPF `Window` that represents a data editor. The `DataContext` of the `Window` is of an observable object (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Each of the observable object's properties is bound to an appropriate widget in the `Window` (`TextBox` for numeric types, `CheckBox` for `bool`, etc.).

I don't want to have "OK" and "Cancel" buttons to persist changed properties; I'd like the underlying data to be persisted to the observable object when the widget loses focus.

To do this, I've handled the `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` and `LostFocus` events for the widget.  My undo framework requires a copy of the observable object representing the current state, and a copy of the new state. The `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event makes a copy of the object, and the `LostFocus` event actually performs the save to the database.

But my problem is this: the Binding on the field doesn't actually update the underlying observable object until **after** the `LostFocus` event is run. The net effect is that changing the text in a `TextBox` from "A" to "B" would persist the data in the field as "A". Changing it from "A" to "B" to "C" would persist "B".

I've put breakpoints in the event handlers and in the setter of the underlying object. Sure enough, `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` runs first, then `LostFocus`, then finally the observable object's setter.

I want to make this as generic as possible, so while I could tell the observable object to update its own property using the `KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs`, I'd need separate event handlers for each field, and there could be quite a few.

Is there any way to get the `Binding` to run **between** the `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` and `LostFocus` events?

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectProperty, StringFormat='{}{0:F5}'}" LostFocus="PersistentTextBox_LostFocus" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="PersistentTextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" />
```

Event-handlers in code behind:

```
private void PersistentTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.ObservableObject.PersistChanges(this.tempObservableObject);
}

private void PersistentTextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {
    this.tempObservableObject = this.ObservableObject;
}
```

`ObservableObject` class (setter):

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ...
    public Single ObjectProperty {
        get {
            return this._objectProperty;
        }
        set {
            this._objectProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ObjectProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, This may be due to the fact that by default the `TextBox` updates the `Source` when focus is lost.

One way to solve this could be to set the `TextBox` `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='{}{0:F5}'}"
```

This will allow the underlying observable object to be updated as soon as a change is made in the `TextBox`, Then you can persist the changes in the widgets lost focus events

Or you could set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` and update the Source in the LostFocus handler.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ObjectProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, StringFormat='{}{0:F5}'}" 

    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       (sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

Comment: I came across that while doing my research. But I was under the impression that modifying each individual character will cause the event to fire. That would be a lot of potential overhead writing to my database, and would also make my undo stack way too fine-grained.

Comment: Ohh, I thought you were updating the DB when the widget lost focus.

Comment: OH... wait a minute. I see your point. Yes, you're right. Let me try.

Comment: You could set the UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit and update the property in the lost focus event handler

Comment: I think `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` works well enough for my purposes. I don't like that it continually updates the underlying object on each keypress, but there's really no reason I can think of to avoid that. This is user think time, so performance really shouldn't be an issue. Thank you!